# New Project - The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I receive this error and in fact, all C# syntax is invalid in all views even for a brand new ASP.NET 4.x MVC 5.X template project in Visual Studio 2015.

I was working for 11 months. It just started yesterday. I installed nothing. Life decided it wanted to suck.

- I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2015.
- I've tried strong coffee.
- I've installed ASP.NET 4.6 from the web again and that *seems to have resolved it for the new project but not for my existing solution*.
- I'm on a branch from weeks ago that went live, to ensure its not a source-code thing.
- I've cleaned everything possible using a super clean VS and all its caches script.
- I've used the reset user data switch.
- I've tried sleeping on it.
- Okay, even though colleagues said it was all fine for them, actually looking myself shows that it is not working for them and clearly hasn't been for weeks.
- The views work fine at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Once I knew this was a code issue that had been allowed to sit for months (!) I was able to double check everything.

I found that in the root `web.config` file `webpages:Version` the version was `2.0.0.0` and also that it had a whole `pages\namespaces` section!

I upped the version and removed the section anything else that was also in the `web.config` under the `Views` folder so there was one true source for these settings.

Also corrected minor version inconsistencies like `5.2.2` to `5.2.3` and `4.5` to `4.5.1` and all is fine.

Luke